# How do I determine the XPaths traversed when I query all child nodes?

Tags: php, xml, xslt, xpath

I have an XML document that represents a directory structure. Directories are represented like `<directory_name>` and files are represented like `<file name="my_file.txt"/>`.

For example:

```
<xml>
    <home>
        <mysite>
            <www>
                <images>
                    <file name="logo.gif"/>
                </images>
                <file name="index.html"/>
                <file name="about_us.html"/>
            </www>
        </mysite>
    </home>
</xml>
```

I want to run an XPath query to get all the `<file>` nodes, but I also want to know the directory path to each file (i.e each parent node's tag name) - is there an easy way to do this with XPath, or will I need to do recursive traversal of the XML tree after I parse it in PHP?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a one-liner Xpath 2.0 solution and for a simple XSLT 1.0 solution. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The following XPath 2.0 expression**:

```
   //file/concat(string-join(ancestor::*[parent::*]
                                   /concat(name(.), '/'),
                            ''),
                 @name, '&#xA;'
                 )
```

**when evaluated against the provided XML document**:

```
<xml>
    <home>
        <mysite>
            <www>
                <images>
                    <file name="logo.gif"/>
                </images>
                <file name="index.html"/>
                <file name="about_us.html"/>
            </www>
        </mysite>
    </home>
</xml>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
home/mysite/www/images/logo.gif
 home/mysite/www/index.html
 home/mysite/www/about_us.html
```

**In case you cannot use XPath 2.0, it isn't possible to produce the wanted result only with an XPath 1.0 expression**.

Then the programming language that is hosting XPath (such as XSLT, C#, php,...) must be used to produce the result.

**Here is an XSLT 1.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="file">
   <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::*[parent::*]">
     <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(),'/')"/>
   </xsl:for-each>
   <xsl:value-of select="concat(@name, '&#xA;')"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the same XML document, the same correct result is produced**:

```
home/mysite/www/images/logo.gif
home/mysite/www/index.html
home/mysite/www/about_us.html
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
<?php 

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$arrNodes = $xpath->query('//file');
foreach($arrNodes as $node) {

$tmpNode = $node->parentNode;
$arrPath = array();
while ($tmpNode->parentNode) {
    $arrPath[] = $tmpNode->tagName;     
    $tmpNode = $tmpNode->parentNode;
}
unset($arrPath[count($arrPath)-1]); 
printf('%s/%s<BR>',implode('/',array_reverse($arrPath)),$node->getAttribute('name'));

}
```